# Generating file from Scala project to be used in building C program from within SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an `sbt` project where the main class can be used to both generate a C header file and depends on compiled C program to run.  In order to build this in `sbt`, I tried adding in a task to generate the header file:

```
lazy val genHeader = taskKey[Unit]("Generate header")
genHeader := Command.process("run gen", state.value)
```

And a task to compile the program that uses the header:

```
lazy val buildRunner = taskKey[Unit]("Build runner code")
buildRunner := ("gcc -I target -o target/hello src/main/c/runner.c" !)
```

Separately these tasks work and do what I expect.  Unfortunately, if I try to wire these together using triggers and dependencies:

```
buildRunner := (buildRunner dependsOn genHeader).value
buildRunner := (buildRunner triggeredBy (compile in Compile)).value
```

The build becomes an infinite loop, because `compile` triggers `buildRunner` which depends on `genHeader`, which uses `run`, which depends on `compile`, which triggers `buildRunner` ...

I've tried to directly call the `main` function in my `GenAndRun` object, but within the `build.sbt` it cannot be imported (since it doesn't exist when the build is first created), and running it externally through `java` using `!` is complicated by trying to determine the classpath to specify with all of the `sbt` managed dependencies.

Any suggestions on how I can break the loop?